# creating trigger error Error: ORA-04076: invalid NEW or OLD specification

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Attempting to create a trigger that looks at the zip in the address table, matches it to the zip in the zipcode table and populate the city state and country of the address table. But I receive the following error:

> Error: ORA-04076: invalid NEW or OLD specification

I'm unsure of how to use the NEW or OLD specification here, can someone help?

```
create or replace TRIGGER Addr_Zip 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF Zip ON ADDRESS 
FOR EACH ROW 
when (address.zip = Zip_Code.zip)
BEGIN
 update address set Address.city = (select City from Zip_Code),
 Address.State = (select State from Zip_Code),
 Address.Country = (select Country from Zip_Code)
 where address.zip = zip_code.zip;
END;
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDDDG/tdddg_triggers.htm#TDDDG52000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of issuing SQL statements we update the values of the current record with PL/SQL assignments using the :NEW. namespace.

```
create or replace TRIGGER Addr_Zip 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF Zip ON ADDRESS 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
    zip_rec zip_code%rowtype;
BEGIN
  select * into zip_rec
  from zip_code 
  where :NEW.zip = Zip_Code.zip;
  :NEW.city = zip_rec.City ;
  :NEW.State = zip_rec.State;
  :NEW.Country = zip_rec.Country;
END;
```

This version selects from ZIP_CODE record into a local variable to avoid multiple selects. Of course this trigger ought to be completely unnecessary, because a properly normalized data model wouldn't have all those duplicated columns. But you probably don't want to know that.

Comment: Thank you. This was very close and allowed me to figure out the missing information below is the code that allowed the trigger to fire successfully.  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Addr_Zip 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF Zip ON ADDRESS 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
    zip_rec zip_code%rowtype;
BEGIN
  select * into zip_rec
  from zip_code 
  where :NEW.zip = Zip_Code.zip;
  :NEW.city := zip_rec.City;
  :NEW.State := zip_rec.State;
  :NEW.Country := zip_rec.Country;
END;